# error when trying to bake action

Tags: animation

I'm trying to solve a problem with rendering by removing all scripts,
so I'm trying to bake the animation, this is the first error I have gotten.
If you know the language of error, I'd appreciate it that you let me know how to master this error

[image: error report]

Comment: I realized that I could just disable 'overwrite current action'
sorry

Comment: Hey! Tip about errors: in blender, these are usually python tracebacks, and it starts with location information, then the end is the actual problem. Like this: Traceback (most recent call last), file “my life” line 4 in “make breakfast”, EOFError: Reached end of file “milk” before done reading.